# perl split function usage

Tags: perl

I have an input file with the following syntax:

```
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset receiver  
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset transmitter  
00331 INFO  [IVS ] sync detected
```

Data Required in the form

```
frame=0000  
info=INFO  
TYPE=[IVS ]  
message=reset receiver  

($frame,$info,$type,$message)=split(what would be the argument?);
```

note: space after IVS before bracket, so cant use space as the separator.

Comment: Is your input fixed width, tab/space delimited, or something else? In order to split the data correctly, you need to know how the data is generated. So: Find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @hobbs but you should use the expanded format for complex regular expressions:

```
while( my $line = <DATA> ){
  chomp $line;

  my ( $frame, $info, $type, $message ) = 
    $line =~ m{
      \A        # start at the beginning of the string
      (\d+)     # capture a string of digits        --> $frame
      \s+       # skip the white space
      (\S+)     # capture a string of non-spaces    --> $info
      \s+       # skip the white space
      (         # start a capture                   --> $type
        \[      #   capture an opening bracket
        [^\]]*  #   capture everything that's not a closing bracket
        \]      #   capture the closing bracket
      )         # end the capture
      \s+       # skip the white space
      (.*)      # capture the remainder of the line --> $message
    }msx;

  print "\$frame   = $frame\n";
  print "\$info    = $info\n";
  print "\$type    = $type\n";
  print "\$message = $message\n";
  print "\n";
}

__DATA__
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset receiver
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset transmitter
00331 INFO  [IVS ] sync detected
```

Answer (score 7):

Wrong question. You don't want to use split. The rule of thumb is: use a regex match when you know what your data looks like; use split when you know what your delimiters look like.

```
my ($frame, $info, $type, $message) = 
    $data =~ /(\d+) (\S+)\s+\[(\S+)\s*\] (.*)/;
```

would be a pretty good start.

Comment: thanks, and also could you point me to some website for a good start to learning perl?

Answer (score 3):

I love regexes, but... TIMTOWTDI as well. )

```
while (<DATA>) {
  printf "frame=%s\ninfo=%s\nTYPE=%s\nmessage=%s\n", 
    unpack("A6 A6 A7 A*", $_);
}

__DATA__
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset receiver
00000 INFO  [IVS ] reset transmitter
00331 INFO  [IVS ] sync detected
```

Seriously, though, the point is that it might be better to split your data-string with one simple `unpack` (*yes, unpack is simple, it just needs a bit of practicing... ))* than with some twisted regexes - of course, if all data columns have fixed width. But sometimes that's just the case. )

Answer (score 2):

You want to split on space, as long as the space isn't followed by a `]`. This means you want to use a negative lookahead in your regular expression. Don't forget that `split()` can take a regular expression as its first argument. It can also take the number of fields it returns, so if you do:

```
my ($frame, $info, $type, $message) = split(/\s+(?!])/, $line, 4);
```

...then you'll get out what you want.

This `split()` splits on one or more whitespace characters that aren't followed by a `]`. It also returns four fields, so you won't split up your `$message` field (everything after the third split will just end up in `$message`).

Comment: thanks, helpful, and i am new to perl, any recommendation on where to learn on web??

Comment: The official documentation on regex is mostly in [perlretut](http://p3rl.org/retut) and [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre). – To learn Perl in general, trust the resource given on http://learn.perl.org and http://perl-tutorial.org. You could have found this information yourself by searching Stack Overflow, this is by no means a rare inquiry.

Comment: @fammi: Also, see [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html). It's freely available for download in various formats.